# DDL to define denormalization rules?

Tags: sql, performance, ddl, denormalization, dml

I've been doing the relational database thing for years now, but lately have moved into Cassandra/Redis territory.  NoSQL makes sense for what we're doing, so that's fine.

As I was working through defining Cassandra column families today a question occurred to me: In relational databases, why doesn't DDL let us define denormalization rules in such a way that the database engine itself could manage the resulting consistency issues natively.  In other words, when a relational database programmer denormalizes to achieve performance goals... why is he/she then left to maintain consistency via purpose-written SQL?

Maybe there's something obvious that I'm missing?  Is there some reason why such a suggestion is silly, because it seems to me like having this capability might be awfully useful.

EDIT:

Appreciate the feedback so far.  I still feel like I have an unanswered (perhaps because it's been poorly articulated) question on my hands.  I understand that materialized views attempt to offer engine-managed consistency for denormalized data.  However, my understanding is that they aren't updated immediately with changes to the underlying tables.  If this is true, it means the engine really *isn't* managing the consistency issues resulting from the denormalization... at least not at write-time.  What I'm getting at is that a normalized data structure without true, feature-rich, engine-managed denormalization hamstrings relational database engines when it comes time to scale a system with heavy read load against complex relational models.  I suppose it's true that adjusting materialized view refresh rates equates to tunable "eventual consistency" offered by NoSQL engines like Cassandra.  I need to read up on how efficiently engines are able to sync their materialized views.  In order to be considered viable relative to NoSQL options, the time it takes to sync a view would need to increase linearly with the number of added/updated rows.

Anyway, I'll think about this some more and re-edit.  Hopefully with some representative examples of imagined DDL.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing an example i.e. some "purpose-written" SQL (real life or fabricated) you are forced to use and its equivalent fantasy/pseudo DDL you'd like to be able to use.

Comment: It's not that one is "forced" to do anything.  As you flatten out your tables you end up with redundant data.  What would be its own entity in a normalized model may not be as/after you denormalize.  In the normalized model if you made a change to a row in such an entity that would be it.  There's no redundancy, so you make the change in one place.  In a denormalized model you'd need to subsequently change that same piece of data in its "n" redundant locations.  What I'm asking is whether it would make sense to give ourselves a way to let the engine handle maintaining consistency.

Comment: With respect to written examples of each that's a good request.  I'll try to put something together and add it as an edit to the question.  Maybe that process will make me realize I'm missing something really obvious.

Comment: "give ourselves a way to let the engine handle maintaining consistency" -- surely we already have the means of writing constraints of arbitrary complexity using `CHECK` or, if your SQL product of choice does not allow subqueries in `CHECK` constraints, triggers? I don't think you can blame the SQL product if you have denormalized but omitted the required constraints ;)

Comment: this isn't about "blaming".  i'm open to the idea that there's no need for what i'm suggesting.  what i'm pointing out here is that check constraints and triggers leave it all to the developer.  i'm wondering whether this is appropriate - whether there are patterns in "typical" "good denormalization"... patterns that should be followed and which (if followed) would allow for a much more structured and systematic management of associated consistency issues in denormalized databases.

Comment: i'm going to invite Quassnoi to weigh in on this.

Answer (score 2):

Some relational database systems are able to maintain consistency of denormalized data to some extent (if I understand right what you mean).

In `Oracle`, this is called `materialized views`, in `SQL Server` — `indexed views`.

Basically, this means that you can create a self-maintaned denormalized table as a result of an `SQL` query and index it:

```
CREATE VIEW a_b
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT  b.id AS id, b.value, b.a_id, a.property
FROM    dbo.b b
JOIN    dbo.a a
ON      a.id = b.a_id
```

The resulting view, `a_b`, were it a real table, would violate `2NF` since `property` is functionally dependent on `a_id` which is not a candidate key. However, the database system maintains this functional dependency and you can create a composite index on, say, `(value, property)`.

Even `MySQL` and `PostgreSQL` which don't support materialized views natively are capable of maintaining some kind of denormalized tables.

For instance, when you create a `FULLTEXT` index on a column or a set of columns in `MySQL`, you get two indexes at once: first one contains one entry for each distinct word in each record (with a reference to the original record `id`), the second one contains one record per each word in the whole table, with the total word count. This allows searching for the words fast and ordering by relevance.

The total word count table is of course dependent on the individual words table and hence violates `5NF`, but, again, the systems maintains this dependency.

Similar things are done for `GIN` and `GIST` indexes in `PostgreSQL`.

Of course not all possible denormalizations can be maintained, that means that you cannot materialize and index just any query in real time: some are too expensive to maintain, some are theoretically possible but not implemented in actual systems, etc.

However, you may maintain them using your own logic in triggers, stored procedures or whatever, that's exactly what they are there for.

Comment: Exactly the sort of feedback I was hoping for.  Thank you!

Comment: +1 but a materialized `VIEW` in Oracle/SQL Server doesn't *have* to have keys and the tables it is based upon don't *have* to have keys either so please don't call these database systems "relational" :)

Answer (score 1):

Denormalisation in an RDBMS is a special case: not the standard. One only does this when you have a proven case. If you design in denormalised data up front, you've already lost.

Given each case is by definition "special", then how can there be standard SQL constructs to maintain the denormalised data.

An RDBMS differs from NoSQL in that it is designed to work with normalised designs. IMHO, you can't compare RDBMS and NoSQL like this

Comment: +1 for a valid opinion, but I think I disagree.  lol... maybe i only disagree because i'm stuck doing "data modeling" in nosql... which i find almost laughable.  i actually believe that nosql development would benefit from integrating relational models somehow (or conversely, that relational databases could benefit from supporting structured denormalization).  i could be completely wrong, but i'm not yet convinced of it.